# spherical mapping scale factor

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I was going through the spherical environment mapping fragment shader of OpenGL Superbible book. It is as follows:

```
#version 420 code

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampled2d tex_envmap;

in VS_OUT
{
   vec3 normal;
   vec3 view;
} fs_in;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    // u will be our normalized view vector
    vec3 u = normalize(fs_in.view);

   // reflect u about the plane defined by the normal at the fragment
   vec3 r = reflect(u, normalize(fs_in.normal));

   // computer scal factor
   r.z += 1.0f;
   float m = 0.5 * inversesqrt(dor(r, r));

  // sample from scaled and biased texture coordinate
  color = texture(tex_envmap, r.xy * m + vec2(0.5f));
}
```

I don't get why the z component of the r is add to 1.0 and then divided by the size of the vector. I know that the values are between (-1, 1). So, first we divid them by 2 and then add them with 0.5 but I don't get why we are changing the z component. Can anyone please help me?